# How to use foreignkey data in django templates using angularJs data?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, datetime

**Models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=30)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(maxlength=40)
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
authors = Author.objects.all().values()
books = Book.objects.all().values()
return render(request,{'authors':authors,'books':books})
```

**demo.html**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
    <div ng-init="books={{books}} >
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">{[{book.book_name}]}/{[{book.author_name}]}/{[{book.date}]}<li>
    </ul>
```

> **Problem 1:**

When we repeat Books data using angularJs it's Not working.I dubug code and find atlast find out the **Book models Field Date** can not work with angularJs.Because Date has syntax like "date:(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 13, 21, 47, 19, 100305, tzinfo=)" So When we remove this field into models and run again angulasJs code, it's Working.**So I want to ask that how can I use Date field data with angualrJs.**

**demo.html**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
   });
<div ng-init="authors={{authors}}"></div>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="author in authors">Author Name: {[{author.name}]}, Books {[{ authors.book_set.all }]},</li>
</ul>
```

> **Problem 2**

I am unable to fetch ForeignKey data through using angularJs data within their syntax.**I want to retrieve Book table data through author Object in templates**

Thanks